# Программное включение/выключение сети

Tags: java, android

Как на андроиде можно программно включить или выключить сеть 3g и wi-fi?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3931094/4829111

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, но на сколько я понимаю это только по поводу wi-fi? 3g таким способом можно включить?

Comment: Вот для 3g http://stackoverflow.com/a/12535246/4829111

Comment: Это я пробовал. Ничего не работает. Да и там написано все для старых андроидов. 2.3 максимум там увидел.

Comment: пермишны в манифесте не забыли указать? там наиписано для 2.3 и выше

Comment: указал android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE. Возможно этого не достаточно. Сейчас попробую все собрать)

Comment: указал <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" /> все равно никакой реакции.(

Comment: странно. А тестируете на реальном устройстве?

Comment: На эмуляторе. Думаете в этом проблема может быть?

Comment: думается что именно в этом причина

Comment: Я попробую тогда на реальном устройстве. Спасибо большое за совет.

Comment: Спасибо большое) Все работает)

Comment: На 5й версии не работает.(